# Cat meeting new cat

Tags: cats, behavior, travel, introducing-pets

I've gotten an awesome grey female Persian cat, who is about 8 months old.

The thing is that my friend is going out of the city and wouldn't be able to take care of his cat for almost 20 days. I want to know if anything might go wrong if I take care of his cat in my house.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am not able to answer your question but a couple things that will help those who can.  How long have you had your cat? Are both cats spayed/neutered?  Has either cat shared a house with others before?

Comment: If you are dedicated to separation, little can go wrong.  Even if you slip up a time or two, cat fights are more loud than serious, so you can grab your cat and get things settled down quickly.  Cats can live fine in a bedroom sized space for 20 days.  Heck, I've lived in Apartments that sized.

Answer (score 5):

Letting the other cat stay in their own home, and visiting to feed them and clean litterbox, would probably be wiser. Or, if you must foster in your own home, plan on keeping them separated or introducing them to each other very gradually. Sharing territories with another cat is stressful, and 20 days is barely enough time for them to work out basic understandings about dominance and such.

Comment: If both cats are comfortable with others and pretty easy-going, you might be able to let them interact -- but you should not plan on it.  In the cat's home is best; segregated in your home is second-best.  I've done the "foster in my home" thing when necessary, but even when everybody got along I still enforced separation when not at home to supervise.  Safer that way.

Comment: Given that @TheMan's cat is still mostly kitten, it might be easier to introduce them on the older cat's territory. But since they aren't going to be living together for an extended period, separation is much simpler for all concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Slowly introduce then around your house and swap the two cats’ bowls after washing them and leave each other’s scents in with the two cats as they will learn their scents. Slowly do it for the best results. If they start fighting you should separate them but most cats are friendly enough to each other. Make sure that your cat is neutured or else your cat may start mating with them and creating a litter of kits that may feel unwanted. Although you do not need to neuter them if you and your friend want kits.

As a summary, slowly him around the house and leave scents around for each cat to smell and separate them if they start fighting. Make sure they are neutured if you don’t want kits.